x2go does not use my ssh agent?
I have an Arch Linux setup and I use x2go to remotely access an Arch Linux server on my LAN.
I used to use I think the standard gnome keyring for my SSH agent, and now I am using gcr instead (per the instructions on the wiki).
I have an ssh-ed25519 key that is locally password-protected, and gcr holds the password to the key and unlocks it. When I ssh to the server, I am not prompted for the password, but x2go asks for the ssh key's password every time. The problem happened before and after using gcr.
X2Go has this page about SSH agent forwarding, but I don't think it's actually relevant, because I think that that workaround is about forwarding SSH agent credentials to the server, and I really just want the credentials unlocked on the client.
